# How to apply Noise texture to specific portion?

Tags: texturing, masking

I made this parabolic image with math function and displaced it with the Displacement node.  As in the screenshot when I applied noise texture before the parabolic math node its applying throughout the surface and showing distorted edges while displacing. I would like to add noise texture only in that black portion.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your *Color Ramp* output **also** to *Math: Subtract* with `1` set as the first value - this way you invert your value, where black is represented by 1, white by 0 and you keep the gradient (smooth transition). Now multiply *Parabola Math* custom node by that inverted value to, so that black areas are multiplied by 1 (the height doesn't change), white areas are multiplied by 0 (the height becomes 0) and areas in between are multiplied by a fraction (get higher and higher towards the black).

[image]

In linear interpolation, the height change is too sudden, so you might want to switch it to **Ease**:

[image]

For a finer control, you might want to use another color ramp to control the displacement transition specifically (this way you don't have to change the color by using **Ease** mode on color going to the shader), though I wouldn't recommend moving the sliders on the 2nd Color Ramp, I was getting ugly results...

[image]